# Replicate pseudocode

Tags: code, pseudocode

I was looking for some LaTeX code to replicate the result shown on the image below. This image is taken from the book "Temporal Verification of Reactive Systems - safety"[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please post a [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minima

Comment: I don't have a MWE because it's an image, i don't know how to make it. I'm asking suggestions.

Comment: Well, the idea is that you should try and to get something that is close to working first. It doesn't have to be perfect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks pretty awful but it looks similar to your image:)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{framed}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{lr@{:\space}l}
        \textbf{in} & $a,b$ & \textbf{integer where } $a>0$, $b>0$\\
        \textbf{local} & $y_1,y_2$ & \textbf{integer where } $y_1=a$, $y_2=b$\\
        \textbf{out} & $g$ & \textbf{integer}
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \begin{equation*}
       \left[\begin{array}{l}
           \ell_0: \left[ \begin{array}{l}
                 \ell_1: \textbf{while $y_1\ne y_2$ do}\\
                    \qquad\ell_2
                    \left[ \begin{array}{l}
                           {\ell_3:\textbf{ await }y_2>y_1;\ell_4: y_2=y_1-y_2}\\
                           \quad\textbf{or}\\
                          {\ell_5:\textbf{ await }y_2>y_1;\ell_6: y_2=y_2-y_1}
                           \end{array}
                     \right]\\
                 \ell_7: g:=y_1\\
              \end{array}
       \right]\\
       \ell_8:
       \end{array}
       \right]
    \end{equation*}
  \caption{A fully labeled program GCD-F.}
  \end{framed}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! It's exactly what i was looking for. It doesn't look awful in my opinion!